# Mapping Cylinders of inclusions

Tags: general-topology, algebraic-topology

So an instructor made the following claim today:

Let us consider the inclusion $A \hookrightarrow X$ of topological spaces, and let M be it's mapping cylinder. There is a natural continuous bijection $M \to X \times \{0\} \cup A \times [0,1] \subseteq X \times [0,1]$, induced by inclusion $X \to X \times \{0\} $ and identity on $A \times [0,1]$. The claim made was that this may not be a homeomorphism. This seems a little strange to me - the map looked closed. If B is closed in the domain, it is closed when intersected with $X \times \{0\}$ and with $A \times [0,1]$, and therefore, closed in their union (This looks like it should be true by looking at limit points in the union - at least, for the spaces I can think of).

I suppose my error is in this preceding sentence, because I don't have a proof of it. In any case I would appreciate a counterexample to the map being a homemorphism.

Answer (score 2):

Your argument is correct if $A$ is closed in $X$ because then $X \times \{0\} \cup A \times [0,1]$ is the union of the two closed subspaces $X \times \{0\}$ and $A \times [0,1]$.

Now consider the following example: $X = [0,1], A = (0,1]$. Let $Z = \{(x,x) \mid  x \in (0,1] \}$. We have $Z \cap (A \times [0,1]) =  Z$ which is closed in $A \times [0,1]$ and $Z \cap (X \times \{0\}) = \emptyset$ which is closed in $X \times \{0\}$. But $Z$ is not closed in  $X \times \{0\} \cup A \times [0,1]$ since $(0,0)$ is cluster point of $Z$.